# Error Installing Java 11.08

Tags: apt, 20.04, java

I’m trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-20-04) to install Java on Ubuntu 20.04 but I keep running into this error:

```
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.5_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
```

Sure enough, when I check my `Downloads/` folder, the sha256 *does not* match what I see on [this page](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/11-0-8-checksum.html).

Any ideas on how to either fix or get around this? Maybe there’s something I’m overlooking (like checking the wrong checksum page?)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a Safari issue. When I downloaded the JDK from Oracle, it turns out Safari was uncompressing the file (so it no longer had the `.gz` ending). Following instructions [from this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/961/how-to-stop-safari-from-unzipping-files-after-download) to stop that default behavior from Safari worked, and the checksum matched :facepalm: